# Hadoop API to download files using pyspark

Tags: azure, hadoop, pyspark, azure-data-lake

I am trying to download a Hadoop file (my hadoop data is in Azure data lake). Used below script, but i am getting JVM error. Any help?
    
    `sc = spark.sparkContext
    URI    = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
    hadoop = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop
    conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
    fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(URI('adl://abcaccount.azuredatalakestore.net'), conf)
    hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile('/test/test_merge.txt','/tmp/')`

Error:
*Py4JError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile does not exist in the JVM*

Note: I tried python subprocess which i dont want use for now.

Comment: Hi @Harish, where exactly are you running this code? Could you please provide more details with the screenshot of the error message?

Comment: on spark, jupyter notebook

Comment: Why use Spark? Aren't there python libraries for Azure Datalake?

Comment: @cricket_007 using API we can make sure of all system resources and faster. Python libraries with Service principle - which i implemented for time being

Comment: Unless ADL downloads can be parallelized, you are making a blocking call to one address. I don't see how starting a JVM or using Spark would improve that

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought sc will download file using multiple threads. I am not sure how Hadoop/ADL calls are internally designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Hadoop version for different version of Azure HDInsight in the offical document [`What are the Apache Hadoop components and versions available with HDInsight?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning) as the figure below.

[image]

The HDInsight 3.5, 3.6 and 4.0 use Apache Hadoop version 2.7.3 and 3.1.1.

I reviewed the javadocs of Apache Hadoop for the API `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile`, then I found there are three type function `copyToLocalFile` with different parameters, as the figure below.

Fig 1. The screenshot for the javadocs of three APIs `copyToLocalFile` of Apache Hadoop version r2.7.3

[image]

Fig 1. The screenshot for the javadocs of three APIs `copyToLocalFile` of Apache Hadoop version r3.1.1

[image]

Meanwhile, other Java programmers got the issue `copyToLocalFile NullPointerException` (It seems to be same as your error) when use `copyToLocalFile(Path src, Path dst)`, and to fix it via switch to the other two APIs `copyToLocalFile(boolean delSrc, Path src, Path dst)` and `copyToLocalFile(boolean delSrc, Path src, Path dst, boolean useRawLocalFileSystem)`.

So I think you may try to use `hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(False, '/test/test_merge.txt','/tmp/')` or `hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(False, '/test/test_merge.txt','/tmp/', true)` instead of your current used one.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure HDInsight jupyter notebooks, you can access the data in the Data Lake Storage account using the following URL pattern.

```
adl://<data_lake_store_name>.azuredatalakestore.net/<cluster_root>/HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv
```

**OR**

```
adl:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv
```

For more details, refer "[use an HDInsight spark cluster with Data lake Storage Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-use-with-data-lake-store#use-an-hdinsight-spark-cluster-with-data-lake-storage-gen1)".

In on-premise hadoop, you can refer to "[Interacting with HDFS from pyspark](https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/interacting-with-hdfs-from-pyspark/)" and "[Using Jupyter notebooks and pandas with Azure Data Lake Store](https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/using-jupyter-notebooks-and-pandas-with-azure-data-lake-store-48737fbad305)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: "use an HDInsight spark cluster with Data lake Storage Gen1". doesnt have info on download. I cant use pandas as i have GBs of data